# Trouble querying the VersionOne query.v1 api

Tags: curl, versionone

I am trying to access my VersionOne (Enterprise Edition) server's query.vi api. I am able to query the rest services and meta.v1, but going to /query.v1 gives a "Trouble executing URL" error.

I am only using curl and browser access at the moment to query the APIs.

e.g.

Works:

```
curl -X GET -u user:pass <baseuri>/rest-1.v1/Data/Timebox
```

Error:

```
 curl -X POST -u user:pass --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d @data.txt <baseuri>/query.v1
```

Where data.txt =

```
{
    "from":"Timebox"
}
```

Also error, going to `localhost/VersionOne/query.v1` is what gives trouble executing URL error.

What is going wrong here? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problems using `curl` with query.v1. It would help if you provided more about the problems executing the URL. The HTTP status code would be a good clue.

Some potential problems:

- The query.v1 endpoint was introduced in VersionOne 13.2, Summer 2013. You would certainly see an error on any release before that.
- If you have selected Windows Integrated Authentication for your on-premise installation of VersionOne, then query.v1 may require NTLM authentication.

Comment: It's returning 500. Error in /VersionOne Application. Runtime Error. When run on the box with VersionOne is how I got trouble executing URL error message. I did check and see that ver is 11.*. I guess that would be the root of my issue?

Comment: Yes, you would need to upgrade. As of this week, 14.1 is available.